# Adjust div as per height

Tags: jquery, css, grid

Following is my fiddle in which I am trying to float div to left and arrange the divs WRT to the height e.g. if 3 divs in a row are not of equal heights then the next three divs should adjust accordingly as per the height of the previous upper 3 divs AND RESPONSIVE on squeeze the divs can easily go to next line.

**Example** http://januarycreative.com/portfolio/

I hope following may explains it all:

[image]

**FIDDLE:** http://cssdeck.com/labs/m3pdvocy

```
.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4, .col5, .col6, .col7, .col8, .col9, .col10, .col11, .col12 {
            background: #801255;
            color: #fff;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px 0;
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to take a look at [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Use uikit.Simply including the uikit.css to ur site home page will make ur block images responsive.http://www.getuikit.com